# Error creating directory: Operation not permitted, can still create files, permissions are correct

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-10.04, file-permissions, fuse

I have a directory mounted over FUSE/SSHFS. It's an Ubuntu 10.04 client connected to an Ubuntu 10.04 server. My user has write permissions for the directory in question, and has been able to create folders before now. Nothing has changed in the configuration. But today, I get:

```
Error creating directory: Operation not permitted
```

...when attempting to make new folders via GUI in any directory that the user can normally write to. I can create files in those places, but not directories. Un-mounting and remounting SSHFS makes no difference.

I don't think it's misconfiguration but rather something has managed to mess itself up. I would prefer not to reboot the server. Anything else I can try?

Comment: First thing I would do is log in via SSH and try do create the directory. That should tell you whether sshfs is part of the problem. If you cannot mkdir that way, too, then I would attach strace to the sshd process serving this login. Of course, maybe the reason is really stupid and SSH-unrelated like subdirectory limit reached...

Comment: Got it, it was something stupid. Out of disk space. It would be nice if the error indicated a space problem rather than a permissions problem.

Comment: Indeed. There are distinct error codes for both cases (`man 2 mkdir`): ENOSPC and EACCES

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved: The Apache log ate all my disk space.